# Single-word "mirror" synonyms

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, poetry, archaicisms

I was looking for the synonyms of the noun *mirror*:

> A surface capable of reflecting sufficient undiffused light to form an image of an object placed in front of it.

The majority of the synonyms are compounds containing the noun *glass* (looking glass, hand glass, cheval glass, etc.)

Are there some single-word, poetic, or even archaic synonyms for it?

Comment: What's wrong with reflector?

Comment: _Speculum_ is probly the word you want. Latin neuter noun for _mirror_ (mirrors were made of polished bronze, pre-glasstech), from the Latin verb _speciō_ 'look at'. For more than one could possibly want to know about the making of a speculum, see Avram Davidson's magnificent fantasy novel _The Phoenix and the Mirror_.

Comment: +1 for *reflector*. Can't get better than that. Even works for mirrors that reflect things other than light (e.g. sound) or that reflect light frequencies we cannot see. Abstracts from shape and material, just as it should.

Comment: @Drew: Not really a synonym then, is it? :) Also, in my mind, both [*reflector*](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Halogen_lamp_macro_02.jpg) and [*speculum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculum_(medical)#mediaviewer/File:Sp%C3%A9culum_en_plastique.jpg) have specific widely known specialist meanings that make it quite dissimilar to *mirror*.

Comment: Then use a foreign word?

Comment: @Amadan: Why would it be "**not really a synonm**"? Any two distinct words have different connotations (always). But the denotations are pretty much the same in this case. You can replace *reflector* by *mirror* pretty much anywhere, and the denotation does not change. Please give an example of a specialist meaning of *reflector* that makes it "**quite dissimilar**" from *mirror*.

Comment: @Drew: As you note, unqualified "mirrors" only reflect visual images (if not used metaphorically, as in "she's a mirror of her mother"), which is in line with its etymology (< French *mirer*, "to stare at"). Yes, "acoustic mirrors" do exist, but that is not what one thinks of when one hears "mirror". The specialist meanings for *reflector* I referred to were the chassis of a lamp that focuses the light beam forward, and various implements in photography that are similarly used to direct light. The latter actually is not a mirror, strictly speaking, as it does not reflect an image.

Comment: As you ask for a specific example, "Give me the reflector" and "Give me the mirror" will produce very different results in a photographic studio, and the distinction is fully denotational. I said unqualified "mirrors", because devices that reflect sound are sometimes called "acoustic mirrors"; however, that is a deliberate and explicit extension of the word's denotation, a meaning the word itself does not normally evoke on its own, at least not in my idiolect. In my mind, an acoustic mirror is no more a mirror than a desert rose is a rose.

Comment: @Amadan: We disagree about *mirror*, in particular about it not being as general as *reflector*. To me an *acoustic mirror* is as much a mirror as is a glass or polished metal mirror that you "stare at" yourself in. Etymology does not tell you what a word means (and you might want to check also the etymology of *reflector*). Even the verbs are synonyms, IMO: *to mirror* denotes the same thing as *to reflect*.

Comment: @Amadan: I guess I do agree with you to this extent: when it comes to light, an unqualified *mirror* typically implies specular reflection, whereas *reflector* does not. The photography example, where an unqualified *reflector* often provides diffuse reflection, fits this.

Comment: @Drew: Etymology might not tell you in all cases what a word means, but in many cases does provide a strong clue. I don't know why you direct me to the etymology of *reflector*, which supports my argument - from Latin "turn back" or "bend back", nothing to do with specifically vision or images. As for the verbs being synonyms: "SPF50 sunblock either absorbs or (reflects/\*mirrors) 98% of harmful UV rays."

Comment: While _reflector_ might be similar, I doubt that most people would recognize it as referring to a mirror. It's most often used to refer to things like the sparkly device attached to bicycles, while mirrors usually reflect clear images. I can't think of a common word that has much the same connotation as _mirror_.

Comment: My first question is, "Why can't you use *mirror*?" Followed by "Why can't you use *looking glass*?" I.e., If you don't want *mirror* then the answer is *looking glass* and if you don't want 2 words then the answer is *mirror*   Perhaps understanding these constraints will help pinpoint an appropriate alternative.

Answer (score 2):

William Perry, [*The Synonymous, Etymological, and Pronouncing English Dictionary*](http://books.google.com/books?id=BlxYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA2722&dq=%22a+looking+glass+a+speculum%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RKgfVM_lNua7igK7oIHQCw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20looking%20glass%20a%20speculum%22&f=false) (1805) offers two synonyms for *mirror*: "looking-glass" and "speculum." As both Merriam-Webster’s Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) and John Lawler (above) point out, *speculum* is Latin for “mirror”; and the word has been in English since the fifteenth century, MW says. Today, of course, it has the rather unpoetical meaning “an instrument inserted into a bodily passage to facilitate visual inspection or medication” (again, MW’s words), but 250 years ago it did not. Here is the definition of *speculum* in Samuel Johnson’s [*Dictionary of the English Language*](http://books.google.com/books?id=m2ITAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PT320&dq=%22speculum+s+Latin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WasfVJ-lK8jnoAS5v4JY&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22speculum%20s%20Latin%22&f=false) (1766):

> SPECULUM. *s*. [Latin.] A mirror ; a looking glass.

The word is certainly old-fashioned (or even archaic) when used in the broad sense of “mirror”—but if people ask you why you chose it, you can gently refer them to Johnson’s Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1682 poem *[Religio Laici](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/religio-laici/)* by Thomas Dryden, the poet simply uses **glass** to mean a mirror.

> If others in the same glass better see
>
> 'Tis for themselves they look, but not for me:

This is backed up in Samuel Johnson's *[Dictionary of the English Language](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AekIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT396&dq=mirror%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iOsfVPD6IeOaygOD34HACQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=mirror%20dictionary&f=false)*:

> Glass: 3. A looking glass; a mirror.  *Dryden*